# wol: MagicPacket received; machine not waking up

Tags: networking, debian, wake-on-lan

I ran down the following checks:

```
>ethtool eth0
-------------------
Supports Wake-on: g
Wake-on: g

>cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
-------------------------------------------
MMAC      S5    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0

>cat /etc/default/halt
---------------------
NETDOWN=no
```

- I alternatively installed a *systemd* `wol@eth0.service` with `ethtool -s eth0 wol g` but it didn't work out either.

I've confirmed and double-checked

- that the MagicPacket is not filtered
- that the ethernet-card in the machine is powered after shutdown
- that the MagicPacket is received by the ethernet-card - it's flashing, when the MagicPacket arrives
- that the BIOS setting is correct

but still, the machine is not waking up.

*Note: The same hardware configuration worked with jessie but now fails with stretch.*

**Q1** What kind of diagnostics can I apply to find out why the machine is not waking up?

**Q2** If the machine is up and running, is there a way to verify that MagicPackets are handled correctly?

Comment: What is the state of the pc when you want it to wake up? Have you turned it off? Have you put it into suspension? Have you put it into hibernation? WOL will only work with the 2nd option, but you can make suspension (sleep) look like hibernation most of the time by setting the correct settings in the bios.

Comment: @LPChip `sudo poweroff`

Comment: yeah, that's not gonna work. Poweroff will turn it off completely, so the computer won't even put voltage on the motherboard to allow it to monitor for the wol packages. In order for this to work, you do at least need to put the computer into sleep rather than poweroff. My knowledge of linux is insufficient to know the exact command to do this, but I suspect it will be `sudo sleep`. Make sure this works first, then figure out how to make the sleep turn the pc into a low power state

Comment: @LPChip I've checked that. The NIC leds are on and they are flickering upon reception of a MagicPacket. As I said, the same configuration worked for jessie but stopped working for stretch. (For some reason, hibernate isn't working on my ancient hardware = homebrewed NAS.)

Comment: the leds being active doesn't mean much. You really need to put the pc to sleep and test that before you can troubleshoot the rest. If it does work in sleep, then you basically know your configuration is correct and it is the powerstate itself. And I'm not talking about hibernation, I'm talking about sleep/suspend. The state that normally keeps all lights on and fan spinning and can be woken up by pressing a key on the keyboard. If that mode cannot wake up using WOL, then your WOL config is wrong. But if it can, then the powerstate is wrong. I'm not saying this is the solution, its a test.(Q1)

Comment: @LPChip `systemctl suspend` is broken but `systemctl hibernate` is working correctly but also fails to wake up on lan.

Comment: hibernate is not good enough. it must be suspend, and you then must configure suspend to turn the pc into a low powerstate.

Comment: You're missing the point. The reason to test it with suspend is to find out where in your chain things are not working. If it doesn't work in suspend either, then your settings for WOL are not correct at all. But if it does work there, then continue to look for other stuff. I know that you can configure suspend to look like hibernation which is the easiest route to set it up. Call it a backup strat

Comment: @LPChip Unfortunately, I can't get suspend to work. I tried both BIOS settings S1 and S3 for suspending. When issuing `systemctl suspend` after a little while the machine initiates a full shutdown. The MagicPacket doesn't bring up the machine before or after the full shutdown again.

Comment: if you power on the machine after the suspend, does it resumes or does it starts from a fresh boot? you can test this by starting a program, then doing systemctl suspend

Comment: @LPChip It's a fresh boot and additionally the HD was not cleanly unmounted. In contrast, if I do this exercise with hibernate the terminal session continues right at the point it left off.

Comment: I see, that makes things really hard to troubleshoot.